# Having problems with jqDock

Tags: jquery, html, plugins, menu

Hello everyone
I'm trying to make a jquery Menu just like the one in Mac, but my jqDock is sticking in the bottum and i want it to be in the header.

Here is the website: http://ydown.totalh.com/.

Here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>yDown - O teu portal de downloads</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/dashboard.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="js/draggable.jquery.ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.jqDock.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import url(style.css);
    </style>

</head>

<body>
<p>
<p>
<p>
<p>
<center><img scr='images/logo.png' title='yDown' alt="yDown" />


<div id="dock">
        <img src="images/finder.png" alt="Finder" title="finder"/>
        <img src="images/dashboard.png" alt="Dashboard" title="Dashboard" />
        <img src="images/mail.png" alt="Mail" title="finder" />
    </div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the CSS code:

```
#dock{
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom: 36px;
    left: 37.5%;
    min-width: 20px;
    max-width: 400px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

#dock img{
    float: left;
}
```

I did only put the jqDock part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the **bottom** style attribute in your dock style.  You CSS for the dock should look like the following, without the **bottom** attribute:

```
#dock{
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 37.5%;
    min-width: 20px;
    max-width: 400px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```